# How can I combine bar and line chart in ggplot2 in R studio from a given data frame?

Tags: r, ggplot2, bar-chart

I have the given data frame dataframe_1

[image]

I am trying to figure out how I can plot a chart using ggplot2 to show the revenue for each year, and grouped by Quarter, and display like this:

[image]

Please let me know what is incorrect with regards to my code below:

```
install.packages("ggplot2")
library(ggplot2)
library(reshape2)

elections <- dataframe_1

dataframe_1_long <- melt(Revenue, id = "Year")
names(dataframe_1) <- c("Year", "Quarter", "Revenue")

ggplot(elections_long, aes(x = Year, y = Revenue, fill = Quarter)) +
  geom_bar(stat="identity", position = position_dodge()) + 
  ggtitle("Quarterly Revenue") +
  labs(y= "Quarterly Revenue", x = "Year") +
  scale_fill_manual(values = c("#53a0ed", "#f71d1d")) +
  labs(fill = "Quarter")
```

Comment: It looks like the main x variable in your example is Quarter and the grouping/filling variable is Year. Do you get what you want when you swap those accordingly?

Comment: no I do not, I believe the error is in the melt() function. Cannot figure a way around it

Answer (score 0):

```
install.packages("ggplot2")
library(ggplot2)
library(reshape2)

ggplot(df4Q1, aes(x = YEAR, y = Overall_CPI, fill = QUARTER)) +
  geom_bar(stat = "identity", position = "dodge") +
  ggtitle("Overall CPI by per Quarter for years 2018-2022") +
  labs(x = "Year", y = "Consumer Price Index") +
  scale_fill_manual(values = c("#4472C4", "#ED7D31", "#FFD700", "#A5A5A5")) +
  labs(fill = "Quarter") +
  theme_light() +
  theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 90, hjust = 1, size = 8),
        plot.title = element_text(hjust = 0.5))
```